# What is a TV series on Disney where people wake up on a spaceship but can't remember its name?

Tags: story-identification, tv, spaceship

I tried hard but can't seem to find the answer.

Basically, 4 or 5 people wake up from hibernation (or something similar) one day to find themselves on a spaceship.

I remember one episode when they find another ship in space, it turns out to be exactly like theirs, and they find their so-called clones, but only older in age. Some of them were dead I think.

In another episode, they get attacked by bugs that eat through metal.

It was on Disney, so it was not so scary. I think its called *Hyperspace* but I could be totally off.

I found out the name of a main female actress "Nicole de Boer".

Comment: Can you expand on "back in the days"? The 1960s? 1990s? Was it live action or animated? Are you sure it was on the Disney Channel?

Comment: back in the days, like 10 years ago, live action not animated, to be honest i am starting to doubt that it was on disney because i amnot finding anything about it on the web

Comment: so it turned out to be called "mission genesis" i dnt know why i thought it was aired on disney

Comment: feel free to tick the little green checkmark down below (next to @Sam's answer) to indicate that it's right!

Answer (score 10):

Since you had the actresses name, a quick search of IMDB gives the answer of:

[Mission Genesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Genesis)

Plot:

> In the future, Earth's entire population is being wiped out by an
>   unstoppable virus. Mankind's only hope for survival is to launch a
>   spaceship stocked with clones in cryogenic freeze, which will return
>   to a devastated planet and re-populate it. Prior to its arrival,
>   however, its crew of 6 is awoken to face a threat to the ship. They
>   must come to terms with the workings of the ship, the dangers faced by
>   their ship, the realization that they are clones, and their ultimate
>   destiny: to save their race.

Comment: Ahh, I remember it under the original title "Deepwater Black". Thanks!

Comment: "Your mission is to repopulate the Earth. Your only resources are your wits, a spaceship, and Nicole De Boer." Tough gig.